# Get undefined variable although I use isset()

Tags: php

I always get "Undefined variable: clicked" although I specifically tell the damn program "hey listen, I know that it is undefined, only do stuff when that variable is defined"...

Am I doing this wrong? I write it like this:

```
<?php if (isset($records[$clicked])) { ?>    
        $("#remove").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/public/index.php/my_team/removefrommyteam",
                type: "GET",
                data: {athlete_id: <?php echo $records[$clicked]->member->id; ?> },
                dataType: "text",
                success:  function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you're isseting `$records` not `$clicked`, check `$clicked` first

Comment: @Ghost strangely `isset($clicked, $records[$clicked])` works, what happened here?

Comment: just separate variables by commas inside it, should handle them, check the answers below, its in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) anyway

Comment: You need to test a variable before using it, ans isset() is testing them from left to right, and stop at the first one that is failing. You should read the link provided by @Ghost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$clicked is your undefined variable, but you are testing $records here, you probably need to test both like this:

```
<?php if (isset($clicked, $records[$clicked])) { ?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($clicked, $records[$clicked]))`